# Getting inner HTML from different ids

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just now starting to try to learn Javascript, so bear with me. I'm trying to get information from a list on one part of my page to a new section with three places at the click of a button.

Each item in the list has its own button, and I need my script to know which place to put the list item based on the number of times the button has been clicked (which should coincide with how many list items have already been added to the list).

I've tried created a script to increase i and take the id of the paragraph into a function, but I can't seem to make it work. I'm hoping that by "counting" the number of times the button has been clicked, it will put each new list item that has been added in the next place in the new section.

I'm not sure how to make the counting part work, though, and it has just occurred to me that maybe the first part of my function constantly remains at zero.

I would really appreciate any help that I can get with this.

Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
<script>    
    function increase(place) {
    var i = 0;
    addToDilly(i, place);
    i++;
}

function addToDilly(num, place) {
    if num = 0 {
        document.getElementById("firstStop").innerHTML = document.getElementById(place).innerHTML;
    }
    if num = 1 {
        document.getElementById("secondStop").innerHTML = document.getElementById(place).innerHTML;
    }
    if num = 2 {
        document.getElementById("thirdStop").innerHTML = document.getElementById(place).innerHTML;
    }
}
</script>

<p id="firstStop">This is a paragraph.</p> 
<p id="secondStop">This is another paragraph.</p>
<p id="thirdStop">This is another paragraph.</p>
<hr/>
<p id="1">Royal Oak <button onclick="increase(1)">Add To Dilly</button></p> 
<p id="2">Ferndale <button onclick="increase(2)">Add To Dilly</button></p>
<p id="3">Chesterfield <button onclick="increase(3)">Add To Dilly</button></p>
```

Comment: You are declaring a function with a local `i` variable... `i` will always be `0`. Count the existing elements in the target instead.

Comment: Also, if you are going to use jQuery (as tagged)... please use it :) `$('#someid')` is much slimmer/nicer than `document.getElementById()`

Comment: I figured as much. How would I go about counting the existing elements?

Comment: `document.getElementById("thirdStop").innerHTML = document.getElementById(place).innerHTML` is the same as `$("#thirdStop").html($('#' + place).html());`

Comment: @SyrupandSass I don't perfectly understand your question

Comment: @SyrupandSass is this you want http://jsbin.com/xuwaku/1/

Comment: @xK0nB1n This is exactly what I'm looking for!! I shall study it and see what I was doing wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SyrupandSass I'm putting it as answer for other's reference and for you to mark it. :) thanks.  glad I could help.

Comment: @SyrupandSass You should choose your best answer now.. if there's nothing else to do or ask If you want some more improvements.

Comment: @SyrupandSass: I would strongly suggest you do start using jQuery (as originally tagged). Your code will be shorter and simpler once you learn the jQuery basics. Doing ID lookups is generally not the most flexible way to write web code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script:

```
<script>
    var i = 0;

    function increase(place) {
        console.log(place);
        addToDilly(i, place);
        i++;
    }

    function addToDilly(num, place) {
        if (num == 0) {
            document.getElementById("firstStop").innerHTML = document.getElementById(place).innerHTML;
        }
        if (num == 1) {
            document.getElementById("secondStop").innerHTML = document.getElementById(place).innerHTML;
        }
        if (num == 2) {
            document.getElementById("thirdStop").innerHTML = document.getElementById(place).innerHTML;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here's the [running example](http://jsbin.com/xuwaku/1)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a complete re-write. If your aim is to update a list of items, just update a list of items (literally) :)

*Note: You originally tagged your question as jQuery, so this initial answer is in jQuery.*

The text you wish to add needs to been in an element related to the button, but not containing the button itself. For this example I placed them before the buttons.

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/t13h54bu/3/

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var $button = $(this);
    var text = $button.prev('p').html();
    var $target = $('#list');
    $target.append($('<li>').html(text));
});
```

and simpler HTML:

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
<hr/>
<p>Royal Oak</p>
<button>Add To Dilly</button>
<p>Ferndale</p>
<button>Add To Dilly</button>
<p>Chesterfield</p>
<button>Add To Dilly</button>
```

Then if you want to limit the items to 3 add this:

```
if ($target.children().length < 3) {
    $target.append($('<li>').html(text));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/t13h54bu/4/